# Add custom text in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to display the custom text under payment method(admin order).

How to display the custom text under payment method in below layouts

1. sales_order_view.xml
2. sales_order_invoice.xml
3. sales_order_creditmemo.xml

[image]

Thanks.